# Complex layout using React and CSS Grid

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

[image]

So I'm attempting to create the above. Is there a smart way of making the menu component? Or does the container element have to cover most of the content component (it has to be a rectangle and in itself use CSS Grid to position the left part and the top part of the menu)?

Comment: Does the menu component need to be like that 'L' shape, or can you split it into to separate parts? Is there supposed to be a space between the menu and the content? More information would be appreciated. EDIT: I have built something along the lines of this: would that be helpful? https://i.imgur.com/okWpgBX.png

Comment: @Neil The hope was to have it as a single component! I would of split it up otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly match your single 'L' shape component requirement, but should get you closer than you were before.

A couple notes worth mentioning:

1. This simply answers your question as a html/css question, not in React style. You could split this up into two components like you were hoping for by using every html/css element other than `body-content`, then having `body-content` html/css as the child
2. Not sure exactly how you want to handle your content, but with this code the `App-Header` will scroll with your content. If you want it to be fixed and stay above the content copy the `MainMenu`'s css, but style it for vertical scrolling.

Hope this gets you going in the right direction.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #203764;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

/* Style page content */
.main-content {
    margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the MainMenu */
}

.body-content {
  padding: 20px;
}


/* The MainMenu menu */
.MainMenu {
    height: 100%; /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
    width: 160px; /* Set the width of the sidebar */
    position: fixed; /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111; /* Black */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="MainMenu">Main Menu</div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <header class="App-header">Header</header>
    <div class="body-content">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```